# How to get index in forEach?

Tags: javascript

I'm inheriting some code from someone else but I never used this way. I used to use

```
for(var i = 0; i<items.length; ++i; {
   items[i];
```

Or

```
myArray.forEach(function (value, i) {
          items[i];
```

But what if I use the following?

```
filtererdData.forEach(regionData => {
   index?
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this.

```
filteredData.forEach((regionData, index) => {
  // your code here
})
```

Ref forEach: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach